# How to align specific ul elements?

Tags: html, css

I want to align some elements to the center of my screen, while leaving others where they are? im pretty new to html and ive tried googling it so if anyone can help it would be appreciated. Here is the code.

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
}
body{
    background-image: none;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center center;
    height:100vh;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
header{
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-moz-flex;
    display:-ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding:30px 70px; 
}

.nav-area{
    list-style: none;
    
}
.nav-area li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-area li a{
    transition: .3s;
    color:#000000;
}

.nav-area li a:hover{
    color:#000000;
}

.btn-area{
    cursor:pointer;
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:10px 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background:#ffffff;
}
```

Here my elements fit to the left and right of the screen. I want some to fit in the center while leaving others where they are

Answer (score 0):

You can use position property to center a item and use absolute ,top : 50% , left: 50% to center item with respect to parent element.

Answer (score 0):

As you've not included your html code, I hope the elements that you need to keep centered are adjacent to one another. If so, you can group them by using a `<div></div>` element and then apply css to that `<div></div>`. Following is code example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <button>button1</button> //other elements
    <button>button2</button>

    <div class="sample">
        <button>button3</button> //elements you want to center
        <button>button4</button>
        <button>button5</button>
    </div>

    <button>button6</button> //other elements
    <button>button7</button>
</body>
```

Here is the sample css code

```
.sample{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    
}
```

Note that the above code center the content horizontally. You can center it vertically by giving a separate height to the div as you want (because in default the div takes the height of the content!) and using the `justify-content: center;` css property to center it vertically **within the div**. Hope you find this answer useful!